# getting error as Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [PageReference].<Constructor>(String)

Tags: apex, pagereference, compile-error

```
<apex:page controller="openPage">
<apex:form>         
   <apex:commandButton value="Open" action="{!openPage}"/> 
   </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

---

```
public with sharing class openPage {
  public pageReference openPage()
    {
        pageReference pg = new pageReference('/apex/Name_Of_The_Page');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is it error during compiling controller class or VF page?

Answer (score 2):

Your org has a class, interface, or variable named `PageReference`. You'll need to reference the system class using its namespace: `ApexPages.PageReference`. I'd recommend that you also change that member's name, but I realize it's not always possible to refactor code (or *easily*, at any rate).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Page.PageName` constructor and it will still work. Note that the default redirect value is true, so you don't have to call `setRedirect(true)`. But even if you do, you could still one-line the whole thing.

```
return Page.Name_Of_The_Page.setRedirect(true);
```

Comment: re: avoiding `setRedirect(true)` -- I didn't know that -- where is this documented. All I know about is this [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm?search_text=setRedirect) and [this one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm?search_text=pagereference)

Comment: @cropredy It's simple enough to prove: `system.assertEquals(true, new PageReference('/').getRedirect());`. Or more tersely: `system.assert(new PageReference('/').getRedirect());`

Comment: Cool.  I learned something!